# Deployement using azure cli, syncing triggers.. timeout

Tags: python, azure, deployment, azure-functions, release

I'm using azure functions in azure devops building an CI/CD pipeline.
The CI part goes well but the final step publishing to azure is stuck at syncing triggers. I am using a httpTrigger.

I have added --build-native-deps argument which allows me to publish just sometimes azure will timeout.

This is the Azure cli script which is run in the release stage:

```
cd Application
source .env/bin/activate
func settings add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME python
func azure functionapp publish scanherkenapp --build-native-deps
```

Normally I expect the release to succeed in ~10 minutes.
However sometimes it takes longer and then it will fail stating:
Response status code does not indicate success: 408 (Request Timeout) or The operation was canceled.

Comment: For my area westeurope the difference might be if it is midday. If it is morning or night the deployment works.

Comment: Deployment is now working most of the time. Seems like azure changed something at their side.